# Document altered and certification Invalid

Tags: digital-signature, itext7

I was signing the document after flattening all fields. While using the *NOT_CERTIFIED* option, I was able to sign the document with no issue, but my objective is to certify the document with the option *CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED* and when I do so I got invalid signatures due to document alteration.

[original pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bug05FqesBYyECR8tSX6gNmaPhB-8yEW/view?usp=sharing)
& [signed pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17uj-wQxDur_P0X1vMUCLiYXgGf9j2hxM/view?usp=sharing)

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SRC);
reader.setUnethicalReading(true);   
PdfSigner pdfSigner = new PdfSigner(reader,  new FileOutputStream(DEST), new StampingProperties());
pdfSigner.setFieldName("signature");    
pdfSigner.setCertificationLevel(PdfSigner.CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED);
PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfSigner.getDocument(), false).flattenFields();  
IExternalSignature pks =
      new PrivateKeySignature(pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, provider.getName());
IExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
pdfSigner.signDetached(digest, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

Comment: Your link does not allow access to the file.

Comment: Could you please check now?

Comment: I had a first quick look. The pdf in the file definitively is not changed, the hash values are correct and there are no incremental updates. Thus, the change Adobe mentions must happen after loading! This may be due to embedded JavaScript i saw in the files. I'll test further the next days.

Comment: I've had another look at the document. As far as I can see none of the JavaScript in the PDF is executed automatically; disabling JavaScript in the Reader before loading the document also does not prevent the signature from being invalidated. Thus, it's most likely due to a different cause. There are inconsistencies in the document. E.g. while the visible pages have been flattened and the AcroForm definition only contains the signature field, there still are form field widgets associated with the invisible page templates. Maybe Acrobat collects them, fixes the AcroForm, and so breaks the sig.